# Unpermitted parameters: user error when passing user params using nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form that collects company information as well as the first user (the company admin). When I submit the form, the company attributes are saved to the db. However, the user attributes are not. I get the error `Unpermitted parameters: user`. I can't figure out why the user is not being created and saved.

I have:

```
class CompaniesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @company = Company.new
    @plans = Plan.all
  end

  def create
    @company = Company.new(company_params)

    @user = User.new
    @user.role = "admin"
    @user.save

    if @company.save
      redirect_to @company, notice: 'Company was successfully created.'
    else
     render action: 'new'
    end
  end

  private
    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def company_params
      params.require(:company).permit(:name, :plan_id, users_attributes: [:id, :company_id, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :first_name, :last_name, :role, :rate])
    end
end
```

and

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

#  include UsersHelper

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    @user.save
    flash.notice = "User '#{@user.first_name} #{@user.last_name}' was successfully created."
    redirect_to user_path(@user)
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.update(user_params)

    flash.notice = "User '#{@user.first_name}' has been updated."
    redirect_to user_path(@user)
  end

  def destroy
  end

  private
    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :first_name, :last_name, :role, :rate)
    end

end
```

and

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  belongs_to :plan
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

and

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  authenticates_with_sorcery!
  validates_confirmation_of :password, message: "should match confirmation", if: :password
  has_many :jobs
  belongs_to :company

end
```

and

```
<%= form_for(@company) do |f| %>
  <% if @company.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@company.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this company from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @company.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name, :id => "name" %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= collection_select( :company, :plan_id, @plans, :id, :name ) %>
  </div>
  <%= f.fields_for :user do |user| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= user.label :email %><br>
    <%= user.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= user.label :password %><br>
    <%= user.password_field :password %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= user.label :password_confirmation %><br>
    <%= user.password_field :password_confirmation %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= user.label :first_name %><br>
    <%= user.text_field :first_name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= user.label :last_name %><br>
    <%= user.text_field :last_name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= user.label :role %><br>
    <%= user.text_field :role %>
  </div>
    <% end %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

and

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140421235514) do

  create_table "companies", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "stripe_token"
    t.integer  "plan_id"
    t.integer  "user_id",      limit: 255
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "companies", ["plan_id"], name: "index_companies_on_plan_id"
  add_index "companies", ["user_id"], name: "index_companies_on_user_id"

  create_table "plans", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "stripe_id"
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "amount"
    t.string   "interval"
    t.string   "currency"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                           null: false
    t.string   "crypted_password",                null: false
    t.string   "salt",                            null: false
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_token_expires_at"
    t.datetime "reset_password_email_sent_at"
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "role"
    t.integer  "rate"
    t.integer  "company_id"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token"

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Company` and `User` are associated with **1-M Relationship** , i.e.,  *Company has_many :users*

In that case, in your view for Company, the nested form should be

```
<%= f.fields_for :users do |user| %>  ## Notice users in plural
```

and NOT

```
<%= f.fields_for :user do |user| %>
```

Refer to the Nested Attributes Examples for **[One to Many](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for-label-One-to-many)**

Currently, `fields_for` is setup incorrectly with singular `:user` so in params hash you got the key as `:user` and again a warning `Unpermitted parameters: user` because of which the user attributes were not stored in database.

Now, as you have setup `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in `Company` model. Controller is expecting user attributes in key `users_attributes` within params hash.

Changing the `fields_for` with plural `:users` argument would result in creation of `users_attributes` key in params hash upon form submission.

**UPDATE**

Company has many users, its 1-M relationship
Only `users` table should have foreign key as `company_id`.
You need to remove `user_id` from `companies` table.

Also, update the `CompaniesController#new` action as below:

```
def new 
  @company = Company.new 
  @users = @company.users.build 
  @plans = Plan.all 
end
```

Comment: I actually tried that. When I change it to `:users` the nested form fields disappear from the page.

Comment: Make sure you have `fields_for` within `<%= %>` and not `<% %>`. They would only disappear if they are not rendered.

Comment: I do. The only thing I did was to make the key plural. I have the same code as I do in the question.

Comment: Kirti spent so much time with me in her chat room to get this resolved. She's so awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Strong params permitting looks fine to me but i think the issue is in the nested form, you used wrong relation name `user` while its `users` which generates a params hash titled with `user` which is not permitted, instead you should do:

```
<%= f.fields_for :users do |user| %>
  #rest of the form elements
<% end %>
```

Comment: See my comment above please.